# Advantages of using Restful Services in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, model-view-controller, service

What are restful services in mvc?what are the advantages of using REST?

I have Goggled it,but haven't got good links.Can somebody help me to understand Restful   services and its implementation in MVC?
I have seen/read the few related links:-

http://www.servicestack.net/

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/23/asp-net-web-api-part-1.aspx

[RESTful services: WCF versus ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444996/restful-services-wcf-versus-asp-net-mvc)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx

Comment: Please be more clear. There's nothing special about using RESTful services vs. non-RESTful services in MVC.

Comment: First of all i want to understand what are restful services

Comment: [so] isn't the place to learn that. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC does not make your application more or less restful. For the most part, rest is about the interactions between the HTTP client and server.
Like in [REST API URI Design Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344215/rest-api-uri-design-approach/17352738#17352738) question, mostly the focus is on the URI design.

The more practical way of thinking or applying REST as the starting point (at least it works for me) is to think in the following ways:

1) Use only HTTP ‘GET/POST/PUT/DELETE’ as the way to model your domain ‘actions’ .  Just like when you dealing with database, all your actions are mapped to [CURD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

2) URI/URL is to identify resources only.  Should never have any ‘actions’ in your URI.

3) The data exchanged should be in the body of the HTTP messages.
Just to simplify the discussions, not getting into how to model the data itself

Two great books on rest.

- [REST in Practice](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805838.do)
- [Restful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do)